# Zend Framework 2 Database Tests create connection

Tags: php, unit-testing, zend-framework2, phpunit

I cant find any Source on the Internet which can explain how to set up a Database Test in ZendFramework 2 with PHPUnit. I have UnitTests running for my Model, but cant find any Source which describes how to Setup the Database Connection in my Tests.
Can anyone give me an Example or Link, how to build a bootstrap.php and setUp() Method for getting my Database Adapter with test connection to work?

Comment: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/tutorials/unittesting.html

Comment: thanks, I have already read this, but I want to test database interactions, and this is not explained.

Comment: It depends on what you would like to accomplish. The link Developer pointed out contains a section about mocking the database connectivity. If you would actually like to include the connectivity in your tests then it would probably best to add a call to beginTransaction in the setUp() method and then call rollback() in the tearDown method. That way you at least keep your database clean while testing.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I found was to define a custom config file and load

```
// UserServiceTest.php
public function setUp()
{
    $this->setApplicationConfig(
        include APPLICATION_PATH . '/config/application.test.config.php'
    );
    parent::setUp();
}
```

And inside `application.test.config.php`, I get the basic application config and override parts of it with custom testing configuration stored in a `config/test` folder like `db.local.php`.